# gpsd not getting signal in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gps, usb, gpsd

dev ttyACM0 shows up in the devices (U-Blox AG in lsusb). cat shows no output.

what am i missing here? This is the "VK-162 Remote Mount USB GPS Dongle" off amazon by stratux

I've tried setting the speed to 4800 which had no result in getting output:
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 ispeed 4800

the box see's the unit:

```
dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: tegraid=21.1.2.0.0 ddr_die=4096M@2048M section=512M memtype=0 vpr_resize usb_port_owner_info=0 lane_owner_info=0 emc_max_dvfs=0 touch_id=0@63 video=tegrafb no_console_suspend=1 console=ttyS0,115200n8 debug_uartport=lsport,2 earlyprintk=uart8250-32bit,0x70006000 maxcpus=4 usbcore.old_scheme_first=1 lp0_vec=0x1000@0xff780000 core_edp_mv=1075 core_edp_ma=4000 tegra_fbmem=0x800000@0x92cb4000 is_hdmi_initialised=1  earlycon=uart8250,mmio32,0x70006000  root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rw rootwait rootfstype=ext4 console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=tty0 fbcon=map:0 net.ifnames=0 quiet root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rw rootwait rootfstype=ext4 console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=tty0 fbcon=map:0 net.ifnames=0
[    0.001785] console [tty0] enabled
[    1.042885] console [ttyS0] disabled
[    1.042959] 70006000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x70006000 (irq = 63, base_baud = 25500000) is a Tegra
[    1.043060] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    1.044032] 70006040.serial: ttyTHS1 at MMIO 0x70006040 (irq = 64, base_baud = 0) is a TEGRA_UART
[    1.044410] 70006200.serial: ttyTHS2 at MMIO 0x70006200 (irq = 65, base_baud = 0) is a TEGRA_UART
[    5.318464] cdc_acm 1-2.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device

lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 125f:a89a A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1546:01a7 U-Blox AG
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But there is no output

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0
<blank>

cgps -s shows blank as well

┌───────────────────────────────────────────┐┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│    Time:       n/a                        ││PRN:   Elev:  Azim:  SNR:  Used: │
│    Latitude:   n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Longitude:  n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Altitude:   n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Speed:      n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Heading:    n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Climb:      n/a                        ││                                 │
│    Status:     NO FIX (0 secs)            ││                                 │
│    Longitude Err:   n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Latitude Err:    n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Altitude Err:    n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Course Err:      n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Speed Err:       n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Time offset:     n/a                   ││                                 │
│    Grid Square:     n/a                   ││                                 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────┘└─────────────────────────────────┘
```